# SourceTree Git Keeping gitignored Folders on Branch Switch

Tags: wordpress, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I just checked wordpress into git. I do have the common folders like wp-admin or wp-contents/upload/ on .gitignore since I don't need to stage them.

However I now switched to another brunch and realized those common folders were deleted from the folder.

Is it possible to keep this folders switching a branch?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your another branch doesn't have that common folders originally.

If you want to have common folders for all branches,

Folders must exist before branching.

Sometimes, one branch push its result to another branch, but I think it isn't good.

It's likely to messy your source code management.

When branch finished you can merge it to trunk, then it can be common folders.